# What is advantage of using XML file instead of text file to load data into SQLite

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

It seems to me that using XML processing would go slower than sequentially reading the data from the text file.
Could someone enlighten me?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on your data. If the data can easily be serialized into a flat file, go for it. XML might be better otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you'd say one would be inherently faster or slower than the other.

A sequential file containing records would seem "flat" to me - one per table.

An XML file is hierarchical, which may include relationships between multiple tables.  That logic would certainly mean more work to code and more CPU to execute, but it's also doing more than a simple sequential file would.

The answer, as it so often is, should be "it depends".  Context is everything.

You're likely to use an XML schema that's as flat as a .csv.

XML parsers are standard stuff, so you don't have to write one.  XML is self-describing - the tags are metadata.  You can use schemas to validate XML.  XML will be more verbose, because tags require bytes.

.csv can be handled by splitting each record at a delimiter of your choosing.  You don't have tags, but you can send a header row.  Validation is up to you and your parser implementation.

I'd say it's a wash.

Comment: Hi @duffymo, thanks for your reply, I'm developing an application that receives data through a file that will be received by a 3G connection, it will insert the records contained in the file, opening the field of each record to insert a SQLite database